# Using $(e^{ik\cdot x})$ as an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{C})$ to define trace.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, trace, quantum-mechanics, orthonormal

I know that $e^{ik\cdot x}$ are not elements of $L^2$. But I believe this is often used in quantum mechanics, and wondered if there is some justification for it.

For example, I have seen the trace of an operator $A$ on $L^2(\mathbb R^d;\mathbb C)$ defined by $$\text{Tr}(A)=\iint A\left(e^{ik\cdot x}\right)e^{-ik\cdot x}\;{\rm d}k\,{\rm d}x.$$

Can we view this orthonormal basis as a limit, or in some weak sense?

Comment: Wait, isn't $e^{ik\cdot x}e^{-ik\cdot x}=1?$

Comment: "For example, I have seen..." - Do you have a reference?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $e^{-ik\cdot x}$ is multiplying the function given by the operator application, $Ae^{ik\cdot x}$. Parenthesis should separate them.